# How to extract report based calculation from BRIO report?

Tags: javascript, java, reporting, hyperion, brio

How to extract report based calculation from BRIO report ?
For example Multiple Requests

[image]

is there public API available to do this task?

Enter code to remove the fields you want to hide from the Results section after the query
finishes processing. For example:

```
// Eliminate fields from the drill path
ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Columns["State"].Remove()
ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Columns["Date Ordered"].Remove()
5) Now select the OnPreProcess event and enter code to put the fields back into the Results
section just before processing the query. That way, any dependent computed items will be
properly refreshed. The corresponding code for the current example would be:
// Add the "hidden" fields so computed items can be recalced
ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Columns.Add("Date Ordered")
ActiveDocument.Sections["Results"].Columns.Add("State")
```

Got the  API which can add/remove the calculated items but unable to retrive the existing column formula for the computed items, Is there any API even to retreive the column formula

Answer (score 0):

If you are you trying to get the code `if(Count ( Account_Id, Account_Id)>1) {'Multiple Requests'}` there is an EIS (Dashboard) code `ModifyComputed()` that allows you to see it as a string: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/ir_user/ModifyComputed_meth.html

If you have no clue what the original code was, I don't think you can extract it, though.